# protractor js e2e tests, using multiple conditions on expect

Tags: javascript

In the current test I'm working on, I need to validate an individual column on an individual row, and check the value accordingly, I think the `expect(...)` is where I'm getting it wrong however I'm not entirely sure, the errors I'm getting are:

> TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'row'
>   TypeError: Cannot call method 'element' of undefined

```
//function in page.js file:

Page.prototype.getSummaryInfo = function () {
    return element.all(by.repeater('accountsSummary in accountsSummaries'))
        .map(function (item, idx, rowNumber) {
             return {
                  index: idx,
                  row: rowNumber.element(by.repeater('accountsSummary in accountsSummaries')).get(rowNumber),
                  currency: item.element(by.binding('accountsSummary.currency')).getText(),
                  totalBalance: item.element(by.binding('accountsSummary.amount')).getText(),
                  totalAccounts: item.element(by.binding('accountsSummary.noOfAccounts')).getText()
             };
        });
};

// calling function in test:

it("should get summary info", function() {
  var details =  page.getSummaryInfo();
  expect(details.row(2)).totalAccounts.toBe("17");     
});
```

Comment: If you have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code, you don't have to use pastebin anymore when asking a question here.

Comment: The error messages are pretty straightforward IMO: Inside your `map` callback, `item` is `undefined`. Inside the test, `details` does not have a `row` method. You fix this by making sure that: a) `item` is always defined or you don't use `item` and b) `getSummaryInfo` returns an object with method `row` or don't call `row`. Not sure what you expect us to do?

Comment: can you please show me how to do this?